# How to retain Font Family in when html is converted to PDF in Itext renderer?

Tags: css, fonts, pdf-generation, itext, font-family

I have a html code which goes like this.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Okay</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <p style="font-family: 'verdana' ; color:blue;">Printing Paragraph</p>
        </div>
        <div style="font-family: 'comic sans ms'; color:green;">Not printing Paragraph</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now when I load this up and print to PDF using I text. The font family is not retained whereas other properties retain. Any leads on how to resolve this ?

Comment: Did you define a `FontProvider`? The `FontProvider` maps the name of a font with the corresponding font program on your computer.

Comment: Well, I did do `Font f4 = FontFactory.getFont(FONT3, BaseFont.WINANSI, BaseFont.EMBEDDED, 12);
        document.add(new Paragraph(RUPEE, f1));` . It doesn't work that way. Also can it not be done without defining Font Provider ? And I was reading contents from a editor and saving it in a PDF.

Comment: Er... I don't see how those lines of code make sense. When you convert HTML to PDF, you need to provide a font provider. The code you show in your comment is to be used when you create your document using high-level objects. Didn't you read any of the documentation?